# Should I use data class even if I implement all of hashCode(), equals() and toString()?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a class which is the parse result of a string, so I have to enforce the toString() to return that source string instead of those parsed values. It also has custom equals()/hashCode() mechanism. Is there any benefit to still mark it as a data class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The auto-generated parts of data classes are:

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
>   properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> ```
> - equals()/hashCode() pair,
> - toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)",
> - componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration,
> - copy() function.
> ```
>
> If any of these functions is explicitly defined in the class body or
>   inherited from the base types, it will not be generated.

The `componentN()` function enables destructuring like `for ((a, b, c) in dataClass) { ... }`

However, data classes **CANNOT be inherited**. (You can define a data class that extends another non-data class though.)

If you think that it is possible that some classes extend your class, then do not make it a data class.

If you think that no class will extend your class in the future, and you maybe need the destruction or copy() function, then make it a data class.

Comment: Thanks for listing all of them. I'm now confident in marking it as a data class. It shouldn't be extended in any way and destructuring may be used.